# Pin a document to the task bar

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I'd like to pin a document to the task bar in Windows 7.  The document in question is a pre-set configuration for an application, and launches the application in the state defined within.  I can pin the application to the taskbar, and then that document in its jump list; however, doing so isn't ideal.  In that state, clicking the icon launches the program in its default state (which prompts for a configuration).

Is there any way to pin the document directly to the task bar, where clicking its icon opens the document with its default application?

EDIT: The application in question is Xming, an X server distribution for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technique assumes that the application in question can take the file as a parameter.

1. Go to the **program's folder**
2. Hold Alt and drag the program into **empty space** to create a shortcut.
3. Now add the arguments from the **Properties** window.
4. Drag it to the **taskbar**

Hope that's all.

Comment: You're a life saver.  It took a bit of research with the different command line switches (and starting from the wrong point), but you definitely pointed in the right direction.

You should update your point 3 to read "Add the arguments -run <path to already-made .xlaunch file>.  The path should be in quotes if it has spaces in it."

Comment: @A. Scagnelli glad it worked! Yes in your case it would be using the -run <location> argument, but for e.g. in Google Chrome I use the -no-sandbox command. This is a more general instruction

Answer (score 0):

You can only pin Applications to the taskbar. Why can't you use the jumplist to launch the configuration?

Comment: That's what I do now.  The problem is that launching the configuration is more like launching the application, and my action is to just click instead of retrain myself for the one app.